# Self-hosted Gitlab with Application Delivery on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine

GKE recently release Application Manager/Delivery addons for GKE. [Application Deliver](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/add-on/application-delivery).

But currently, Application Manager/Delivery only supported Github.com and Gitlab.com. Is there any plan or release channel to support self-hostd Gitlab instances? And are there any workarounds for this at the moment?

```
Initialize an application with Anthos Application delivery framework.
APP_NAME should conform to definitions of label and subdomain in DNS (RFC 1123: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1123)

Usage:
  appctl init APP_NAME --app-config-repo [--deployment-repo] [--config-path] [flags]

Examples:
  # Initialize an app from scratch and create a remote app repository.
  appctl init myapp --app-config-repo github.com/myorg/myapp

  # Initialize an app from an existing repository.
  appctl init myapp -app-config-repo github.com/myorg/myapp

  # Initialize an app and customize the configuration path (default is ./config).
  appctl init myapp --app-config-repo github.com/myorg/myapp --config-path myappconfig

  # Initialize an app and customize the deployment repo.
  appctl init myapp --app-config-repo github.com/myorg/myapp --deployment-repo github.com/myorg/myapp-env


Flags:
      --app-config-repo string        The url of the application configuration repository. It should be in the form of "[https://]<github|gitlab>.com/<ORG or USER>/<REPO>".
                                      
      --config-path string            The relative directory that contains the application's kubernetes resource configurations. Default to "./config".
      --deployment-repo appctl init   the url of the deployment repository. It should be in the form of "[https://]<github|gitlab>.com/<ORG or USER>/<REPO>".
                                      If not provided, appctl init will use a default url in the form of "[https://]<PLATFORM>.com/<ORG or USER>/<APP_NAME>-deployment" where PLATFORM and ORG/USER are from --app-config-repo.
  -h, --help                          help for init
```

Comment: Is there any plan or release channel to support Gitlab Private? <-- I think that's the question not for a StackOverflow community.

Comment: That is a good point, my second question is there any workaround for that? Or it is up to the GCP team to decide?

Answer (score 0):

The [Managing applications with Application Delivery](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/add-on/application-delivery) "How To" on GCP documentation portal says that one of the prerequisites is

> "A GitHub or GitLab account with permissions to create a **private repository**. Application Delivery supports only GitHub and GitLab repositories."

That made me think that both GitHub and GitLab private repos are supported. So I have re-checked that myself by following the "How To" guide and it worked fine (at least on my setup).

```
kiwi@suse-laptop:~/$ cat /etc/SUSE-brand 
openSUSE
VERSION = 15.1

kiwi@suse-laptop:~/$ git version
git version 2.26.1

kiwi@suse-laptop:~/$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15+", GitVersion:"v1.15.11-dispatcher",  GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-04-21T04:42:07Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.17", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15+", GitVersion:"v1.15.11-gke.12", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-04-20T22:33:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.17b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Additionally there is another recent tread at [GitLab Issue Tracker](https://gitlab.com/MrTrustor/helloworld/-/issues/1) that confirms that the Application Delivery works with the private GitLab repo.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, my question is on Private Gitlab instance (Self-hosted Gitlab) not about Gitlab.com 's private repository. For the private repository I have tested it and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, this answer doesn't really help. The question is about self-hosted gitlab and if there is a workaround for it.